How do I share WP core files in wp-env?
I'm new to wp-env, and I'm wondering if it's possible to have one set of WP core files shared across my projects so I don't need to have new core files for every project.
Currently, I map the whole wp-content folder locally so I can work on themes and plugins, but the core files are all kept within the wp-env directory, which are the Docker containers. Each project container has not only one set of WP core files, but two, as it creates a test environment as well.
My directories look like this:

wp-env (holds wp core files in docker containers)

project-1-docker-container
project-2-docker-container


wordpress (holds projects, each containing wp-content and a .wp-env.json file)

project-1
project-2



I run wp-env start within each of these project directories within the wordpress directory, as that's where the .wp-env.json files are.
Each one of those docker containers within wp-env is about 500mb, which could get very large once I add more projects. Can I not just have one set of shared core files so when I run wp-env start it references those files?
I've played around with creating a directory that holds core files, then referencing that with my .wp-env.json file in the core field, but didn't get too far.
Thanks!
